# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

I have a problem when i install sonata bundle or fosuserbundle in terminal with command :

```
php ../composer.phar require sonata-project/admin-bundle
```

i have this error

```
pros-MBP:BigManage pro$ php ../composer.phar require sonata-project/admin-bundle
Using version ^3.17 for sonata-project/admin-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.18 requires symfony/dependency-injection v2.0.18 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.17 requires symfony/dependency-injection v2.0.17 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle 2.0.7 requires symfony/translator 2.0.7 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for desarrolla2/blog-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by desarrolla2/blog-bundle[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - desarrolla2/blog-bundle dev-master requires knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle ~2.4.1 -> satisfiable by knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle[2.4.1, 2.4.2].
    - knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle 2.4.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle 2.4.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.36|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.37|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.38|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.39|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.40|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.41|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.42|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.2.7, required as 3.2.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.2.7].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

can you help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possible-error message in the composer output

```
Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
```

the repo https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle  doesn't seem to have the first issue. 
This could possibly the second issue. As in you have to check your composer.json to make sure if you requirements match with

```
"php": "^5.3 || ^7.0",
"doctrine/common": "^2.2",
"doctrine/inflector": "^1.0",
"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.1.1",
"sonata-project/block-bundle": "^3.2",
"sonata-project/core-bundle": "^3.1",
"sonata-project/exporter": "^1.7",
"symfony/class-loader": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/config": "^2.3.9 || ^3.0",
"symfony/console": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/dependency-injection": "^2.3.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/expression-language": "^2.4 || ^3.0",
"symfony/form": "^2.3.5 || ^3.0",
"symfony/http-foundation": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/property-access": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/routing": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/security-acl": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/security-bundle": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/templating": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/translation": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"symfony/twig-bridge": "^2.3.5 || ^3.0",
"symfony/validator": "^2.3 || ^3.0",
"twig/extensions": "^1.0",
"twig/twig": "^1.28 || ^2.0"
```